# Angular 4: ng serve work well but ng build --prod fails

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I tried to run `ng serve` it runs without any error, but when I tried to create a production build using '`ng build --prod`' it stopped with error below. I tried to tweak with the version still no success. Then some other issue occurred like other API version compatibility issue. Any help will be highly appreciated.

> ERROR in ./src/main.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in
>   'D:\000PS\workspace_ui\dashboard\src' ERROR in Error: Metadata version
>   mismatch for module
>   D:/000PS/workspace_ui/dashboard/node_modules/ngx-pipes/src/app/index.d.ts,
>   found version 4, expected 3
>       at StaticSymbolResolver.getModuleMetadata (D:\000PS\workspace_ui\dashboard\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:25755:34)
>       at StaticSymbolResolver._createSymbolsOf (D:\000PS\workspace_ui\dashboard\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:25543:46)
>       at StaticSymbolResolver.getSymbolsOf (D:\000PS\workspace_ui\dashboard\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:25524:14)
>       at D:\000PS\workspace_ui\dashboard\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24381:30
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at extractProgramSymbols (D:\000PS\workspace_ui\dashboard\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24380:79)
>       at AotCompiler.analyzeModulesAsync (D:\000PS\workspace_ui\dashboard\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23936:47)
>       at CodeGenerator.codegen (D:\000PS\workspace_ui\dashboard\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.js:32:14)
>       at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.codeGen (D:\000PS\workspace_ui\dashboard\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:73:30)
>       at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then (D:\000PS\workspace_ui\dashboard\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:428:58)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

Please find package.json for reference:

```
{
  "name": "dashboard",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/router": "4.4.4",
    "@ngui/map": "0.18.3",
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.26.14",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.5",
    "bootstrap-notify": "3.1.3",
    "bootstrap-select": "1.12.2",
    "bootstrap-switch": "3.3.4",
    "bootstrap-tagsinput": "0.7.1",
    "chartist": "0.9.4",
    "chartist-plugin-zoom": "0.4.0",
    "chartjs-plugin-zoom": "0.5.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "datatables": "1.10.12",
    "datatables.net-bs": "1.10.12",
    "datatables.net-responsive": "2.1.1",
    "easy-pie-chart": "2.1.7",
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "4.17.47",
    "fullcalendar": "3.4.0",
    "jasny-bootstrap": "3.1.3",
    "jquery": "1.12.4",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "mdbootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "ng2-fab-speed-dial": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "ngx-pipes": "^1.6.5",
    "nouislider": "9.2.0",
    "npm": "^5.8.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "time-ago-pipe": "1.2.1",
    "twitter-bootstrap-wizard": "^1.2.0",
    "web-animations-js": "2.2.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.4",
    "@types/bootstrap": "3.3.32",
    "@types/chartist": "0.9.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "1.10.31",
    "@types/node": "6.0.73",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "2.0.0",
    "tslint": "4.5.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like `ngx-pipes` is incompatible with your current angular version or an issue with the library itself.

Comment: ya looks , but ng serve work well , also is there any option by which i can create a prod  build, with  or without adjusting relative version?

Comment: try downgrading `ngx-pipes`

Comment: You can try ng build --target=production.. Do let me know whether it's working or not.

Comment: I tried to build using ng build --target=production, but it fails again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your angular version is 4.4 and ngx-pipes angular version is 5 or above. So install ngx-pipes with version that is compatible with your angular project.

Check inside node_modules/ngx-pipes/package.json to find ngx-pipes version.